Configuring Opentelemetry for aws lambda leveraging opentelemetry aws lambda layers
I am new to opentelemetry. I am trying to configure zero-code otel instrumentation for aws lambda, so that it could push matrices and traces to SingnalFX.
Implemented lambda using nodejs. I have configured below aws layers
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:184161586896:layer:opentelemetry-collector-arm64-0_12_0:1
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:184161586896:layer:opentelemetry-nodejs-0_11_0:1

Below are the environment variables I have setup for my nodejs lambda
AWS_LAMBDA_EXEC_WRAPPER /opt/otel-handler
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_METRICS_ENDPOINT https://ingest.us0.signalfx.com
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT https://ingest.us0.signalfx.com/v2/trace
OTEL_SERVICE_NAME ms-config-container-dev-lambda
SIGNALFX_METRICS_TOKEN <metrics_token>
SIGNALFX_TRACES_TOKEN <traces_token>
STAGE dev

But after re-deploying my lambda with above configuration, I am seeing below errors in cloudwatch logs. I am guessing the either the environment variables are not correct or I might have missed any steps.

{
"stack": "Error: PeriodicExportingMetricReader: metrics export failed (error OTLPExporterError: Not Found)\n    at doExport
(/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/build/src/export/PeriodicExportingMetricReader.js:76:23)\n
at process.processTicksAndRejections
(node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at async
PeriodicExportingMetricReader._doRun
(/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/build/src/export/PeriodicExportingMetricReader.js:84:13)\n
at async PeriodicExportingMetricReader._runOnce
(/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/build/src/export/PeriodicExportingMetricReader.js:55:13)\n
at async PeriodicExportingMetricReader.onForceFlush
(/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/build/src/export/PeriodicExportingMetricReader.js:96:9)\n
at async PeriodicExportingMetricReader.forceFlush
(/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/build/src/export/MetricReader.js:141:13)\n
at async MetricCollector.forceFlush
(/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/build/src/state/MetricCollector.js:58:9)\n
at async Promise.all (index 0)\n    at async MeterProvider.forceFlush
(/opt/nodejs/node_modules/@opentelemetry/sdk-metrics/build/src/MeterProvider.js:102:9)\n
at async Promise.all (index 1)",
"message": "PeriodicExportingMetricReader: metrics export failed (error OTLPExporterError: Not Found)",
"name": "Error" }

Please help me in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance.
